# How to select 1:n related records which are minimum 2 per type in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, count, group-by, relational

I have the following database tables.

```
my_left_table 
left_id      name 
1            A
2            B
3            C

my_right_tabe
right_id    thing     left_id_fk    status
1           D          1            new
2           E          1            new
3           F          2            old 
4           G          3            old
5           H          3            new
6           I          3            new
7           J          1            old
8           K          2            old
9           L          2            new
10          M          3            old
11          N          3            old
12          O          1            new
```

My desired result is as follow.

```
my_left_table 
left_id     name 
3            C
```

How do I select the left records which its right records have `AT LEAST 2 status` is `new` AND `2 status` is `old`. For example, left_id 1 is not the target because three of its right records have the status new but only one record has the status old.

So far I have is.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(my_right_tabe.left_id_fk) AS count_left_id_fk  
FROM my_left_table 
INNER JOIN my_right_tabe 
ON my_left_table.id = my_right_tabe.left_id_fk 
GROUP BY my_right_tabe.left_id_fk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the HAVING clause in MySQL
Like the following

```
SELECT my_left_table.left_id, my_left_table.name
FROM my_left_table 
INNER JOIN my_right_tabe 
ON my_left_table.left_id = my_right_tabe.left_id_fk 
GROUP BY my_right_tabe.left_id_fk
HAVING SUM(my_right_tabe.status="new") >= 2 AND
       SUM(my_right_tabe.status="old") >= 2
```

Comment: There is one more thing I forgot to mention. The status is more than just new and old, but dynamic. Cannot say what those status values are. How to solve that?

Comment: Then you should look at what Samir wrote in the other Answer, but if you want it to be totally dynamic you would have to change the having clause to: HAVING SUM(status_calc) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(status)) FROM my_right_tabe) ;

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve desired results by first grouping the values and then check its total. If its >= 2 pull that record.

Here is the query

```
SELECT z.*
FROM
(
    SELECT a.left_id, name, status, IF(COUNT(*) >=2, 1, 0) AS status_calc
    FROM my_left_table a JOIN my_right_table b
    ON a.left_id = b.left_id_fk
    GROUP BY left_id, status
) z
GROUP BY z.left_id
HAVING SUM(status_calc) = 2;
```

*[Working Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b74881/3)*